# Convergence of $\sum^n_{k=1}\frac1k$ after removing terms containing the digit $p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We know that $\sum^n_{k=1}\frac1k$ diverges. But if I were to pick a digit $p$ so that $p$ is an integer between $0$ and $9$ inclusive, and then I removed all terms in the sum $\sum^n_{k=1}\frac1k$ containing the digit $p$, what does the sum converge to, if it converges at all?

After a few hours considering this problem, I have decided that the problem is beyond me and I need help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series

Comment: Very cool! Thanks, L.F.